# How can I get a path to a specific widget in order to share it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using share plugin(https://pub.dev/packages/share) to share a specific post from a list of posts.

Here is the code that triggers the share functionality

```
 onSharePressed: () => Share.share(
                  'Check out this post : here I want to give a path to this post'),
```

[image]

Is there any way to provide a path that gets me to this widget?

and when i press share it gives me that string.
[image]

Comment: i guess we need more code :-D or information

Comment: What you are looking for is deep linking, each post can have an ID or route and based on that you route to this widget with deeplinking and fetch the corresponding post based on the ID in the URL. i.e: 'Check out this post : myapp://myDomain.TLD/posts/{postId}

Comment: @AymanBarghout the thing is, I don't want to acces somthing from the internet. Let's say, 2 users have my app and one is sharing a post to the other user(with mail for instance) the other user when taps the link it opens the app at the post that was sent. Can I use deep linking for this?

Comment: Yes, that's what deep linking is for!
You send him to that widget in your app with some queries like `postID` and then you fetch the post data from the internet in the app, I don't think you show posts from an offline database so it should work :D